# Spring Integration DSL Transform one object to other

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I would like to convert incoming message to one POJO class object, from the converted POJO class object to other POJO class object. Like, Message->Delivery1->Delivery2

```
public Message<Delivery2<?>> tranform(Message<String> message){
//Want to write Code to transform the "message" to "delivery1" and from "delivery1" to "delivery2".
}
```

What I did and it is working: (Here I would like to again transform Delivery1 to Delivery2)

```
private JsonObjectMapper<JsonNode, JsonParser> objectMapper;
public Message<Delivery1<?>> tranform(Message<String> message){
  return Message<Delivery1<?>> Transformers.fromJson(Delivery1.class, objectMapper).transform(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what is your concern. you definitely can chain transformers with Java DSL:

```
.transform(Transformers.fromJson(Delivery1.class, objectMapper))
.<Delivery1, Delivery2>transform(toDelivery2Transfomer, "transform")
```

Of course you can do that in a single custom method calling a couple transformation functions.

Also it is not clear why don't transform directly to `Delivery2` from JSON. Why do you need that intermediate `Delivery1`?